# convolution and test function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

> Let $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{R}) $ and $f(x)=C \varphi(x)$ , C constant with $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1$.
> Let $0 < \alpha < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\psi_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}f(\frac{x}{\alpha})$

I proved with a change of variables that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(x)dx=1$.

> Now let $\ell>0$ and
> $$E(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1  \quad \text{if} \quad 0\le x\le \ell, \\
> 0 \quad \text{else.}\end{cases}
> $$

My question is how prove that the convolution $h=\psi*E \in D(\mathbb{R}) $ and $h \equiv 1$ in $[\alpha; \ell-\alpha]$

Comment: What is $[\alpha, \ell - \alpha]$ if $\ell > \alpha$?

Comment: you mean what is $[\alpha;l-\alpha]$ if $ \alpha > l $ i has also touched Ambiguity at this point .

Comment: Yes, I meant that. What are $C$ and $h$ supposed to be?

Comment: We have $$(\varphi \ast E)(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} \varphi(\tau) E(t - \tau) d \tau = \int_{t - \ell}^{t} \varphi(\tau) d \tau,$$ right?

Answer (score 1):

You are just willing to say that if $\phi \in L^1$ is supported on $[-r,r]$ then for $\ell > 2r$ $$\phi \ast 1_{[0,\ell]}$$ is constant $=\int_{-r}^r\phi(x)dx$ on $[r,\ell-r]$,

and $0$ on $(-\infty,-r]\cup [\ell+r,\infty)$.

If $\phi$ was $C^\infty$ then $\phi \ast 1_{[0,\ell]}$ is $C^\infty$ because its derivative is $\phi(x)-\phi(x+\ell)$.